# Filter data with group by ; DataTable.select / Datatable row filter ;

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, ado.net, dataset

I am reading data from multiples server in separate datasets and then merging it in a single dataset.

here is sample structure

```
server agent_code callsuccess calls failed  
1        1             5            2  
2        2             12           2  
3        1             25           5  
4        3             15           10
```

After that I want sum of callsucess and callfailed group by agent code , [ignoring server]

I have tried datatable.select() and rowfilter method but doesn't get any luck yet! :-)

Comment: tried something as `dsAll.Tables[0].Compute("sum(callsuccess)", "group by agent_code");`

Comment: You can use Linq to do this. Here are some examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb738016#sumgrp

Comment: Here is another c sharp example (SUM example is right at the bottom) [LINQ to DataSet - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386991.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for generous co-operation, but I am using .net 2.0

Comment: Your can do it before merging by adding a relationship. Please check the **In Memory Group-By** of this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810291.aspx. Basically, you have to add a relationship between two datatables and get the sum using Compute() method. There is a good example there in VB.